# a better understanding of Schema in SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server

Like the title, I'm still a rookie of SQLServer, when I creating a table 'Mytable', it's showed 'dbo.Mytable' in the database

But can anyone give me a better understanding of schema?

Also, in the book Server 2008 TSQL, Itzik says 'in your database, table belongs to schema, schema belongs to your own database'

then how to define schema?

Comment: Here's a good blog post about schemas in sql server: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/07/sql-server-importance-of-database-schemas-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "new flavor" is to use schema's like namespaces.

The default of "dbo" goes back a long ways.

But I treat the schema name as part of the name.

Like, I never write

```
Select * from Employee
```

I always write

```
Select ColA, ColB from dbo.Employee
```

I'd get a copy of the AdventureWorks database, it has good examples.

**EDIT..........**

Microsoft SQL Server 2005 introduced the concept of database object schemas. Schemas are analogous to separate namespaces or containers used to store database objects. Security permissions apply to schemas, making them an important tool for separating and protecting database objects based on access rights. Schemas reduce the work required, and improve the flexibility, for security-related administration of a database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: how they organize all the tables under them?

Comment: You can add "objects" under a schema.  Which are tables, views, stored procedures, user defined function....etc, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to SQL Server and to databases in general, then the concept of schema probably is confusing.  A basic understanding is:

```
A schema is the unit of security (as described [here][1] if you must know).

A database is the unit of backup and recovery.
```

If you are new to SQL Server, security may not be top on your mind.  You think "users have access to databases, so databases are the unit of security".  Not only does that make sense, but that is how many databases implement security.

However, it is not particularly flexible.  Say we are both working in a database, and I want to give you execute permissions on all my stored procedures -- even ones I create in the future.  With a schema, it is easy.  I grant you execute permission on the schema, anything new you can use.

If I had to do this at the database-level, then I would have a few inferior options:

1. Grant you access to *all* stored procedures.  Even the one that deletes everything on the server that only special people have access to.  And, even the ones developed by someone else in the database.
2. Grant you access to all *existing* stored procedures.  But then I add a new one for the application, and your application stops working.
3. Break everything up into different databases, but then that becomes a management nightmare.

This is only intended as an example of how schemas manage security within a database.  SQL Server makes them pretty easy to use by defaulting everything to `dbo` (which stands for "database owner").  Their power only becomes apparent when you have a situation needing them.  In the meantime, just get used to using `dbo` in certain contexts (such as four-part naming for accessing objects on linked servers and for calling user-defined functions).

Answer (score 1):

Schema is a container for DB objects.  It's a convention to help you better organize your tables.